# Regular Expression for characters but number and space optional using asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Regular Expression for characters but number and space optional using asp.net web forms.

These are acceptable strings:

```
 Mazhar
 mazhar123
 mazhar khan1
```

These are not acceptable:

```
1233444
@@@@@@
Mazhar@kkk
```

All Special characters should not be acceptable as well.

Comment: If you dont know then please dont down vote, my question is not this Learning Regular Expressions. @Biffen

Comment: What question? All I see are requirements.

Comment: Not necessarily. That question has two important things that this one is lacking: An attempt at a solution and an actual question.

Comment: Show me the question like my requirement then place as duplicate, I dont know you are senior in this stack over flow. @Biffen

Comment: No dear vera rind, I am not getting logic to get answer thats what posted here and I know you people for helping that what posted na. @Verarind

Comment: @MMK I don't understand what you're trying to say. I marked it as a duplicate of that one because this is basically a give-me-a-regex ‘question’.

Comment: I shown na above that should only acceptable others all not that is my question. @Biffen

Comment: At least please remove from duplication question na and please remove down vote, we are fresher in this stack over flow, you people help to new users any think will happens. @Biffen

Comment: Do you accept *leading spaces*, e.g. `"   abc 123"`? *trailing spaces*, e.g. `"abc 123     "`? *double spaces* e.g. `"abc    123"`? Shall the valid string start with character, e.g is `"123abc"` accepted?

Comment: No double Space should not allowed and other thank ok, we can not give that much validations na, please update your answer and let allow this type of valiation also "123abc". @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is *vague* one. There're some issues which are still open:

1. Do you accept *leading* spaces e.g.  `"      Mazhar"`?
2. Do you accept *trailing* spaces e.g. `"Mazhar      "`?
3. Do you accept *double* spaces e.g.   `"Mazhar   123"`?
4. Can a valid string start with *digit*? e.g. `"123 Mazhar"`

In case answers are *No, No, Yes, No* you can put it like this

```
  // The pattern, you probably are looking for:
  string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z]+([A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9])*$";

  string[] tests = new string[] {
    // your test cases (valid strings)
    "Mazhar", "mazhar123", "mazhar khan1",
    // your test cases (invalid strings)
    "1233444", "@@@@@@",  "Mazhar@kkk",
    // my test cases (leading space, trailing space, double space, starts with digit)
    " Mazhar", "Mazhar ", "Mazhar    123", "123Mazhar"
  };

  var report = tests
    .Select(item => Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern)
      ? $"{item,15} is valid"
      : $"{item,15} is NOT valid");

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, report));
```

The outcome is

```
         Mazhar is valid
      mazhar123 is valid
   mazhar khan1 is valid
        1233444 is NOT valid
         @@@@@@ is NOT valid
     Mazhar@kkk is NOT valid
         Mazhar is NOT valid  // leading spaces
        Mazhar  is NOT valid  // trailing spaces
  Mazhar    123 is valid      // we accept double spaces
      123Mazhar is NOT valid  // starts with digit
```

Comment: Thank you very much will check and update answer. @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: You are father of regular expression thank you very much. @Dmitry Bychenko

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression: `^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$`

I would recommend you to try for a solution yourself and refer to the question suggested by Biffen.